# How to configure Laravel on remote server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, remote-server

I'm new on Laravel. Installed laravel on my remote server ubuntu14.04. I create a project on /www/html as blog. Then run

```
php artisan serve --host=10.x.x.12 --port=8010.
#Laravel development server started: <http://10.x.x.12:8010>
```

Its ok . I can access laravel from my local windows with that link.

The problem is I use putty for remote access. When I closed putty, I can't access anymore 10.x.x.12:8010.

How to use laravel server continuously from remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nohup` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)) so the program does not exit when the terminal session ends.

```
nohup php artisan serve --host=10.x.x.12 --port=8010 &
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I try nohup. It returns nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’

Comment: Does it still exit when you close putty?

Comment: With nohup command,  #Laravel development server started: <http://10.x.x.12:8010> does not show and cant access id. I tried nohup php artisan serve --host=10.x.x.12 --port=8010 </dev/null &>/dev/null &. Its avoid to the message but still does not work for starting laravel.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Try adding `&` at the end to run it in background.

Comment: It returns the `PID` (process id number) when you run it. Use `kill <PID>` to kill the process. If you forget the `PID` run `ps aux | grep "php artisan serve"` to find the `PID`.